# PSA: Please don't post images of text

Tags: discussion

When asking or answering questions, please don't post screenshots of text. This is a very bad idea because:

1. You can't copy/paste the commands into answers, google searches, local files to work on a solution, or anything else.
2. They won't come up when searching.
3. The post is heavier (in terms of the amount of data) and will take longer to load. This can be a serious problem for people with slow connections.
4. The post is useless to people using text-based browsers or who have disabled the displaying of images.
5. The post is useless for people who have sight problems and are maybe accessing the site using text-to-speech software.
6. The image is only guaranteed to be legible on YOUR monitor.  Anyone with a different monitor (e.g. different DPI, higher resolution, viewing on a tablet etc) might be unable to read the tiny little fonts.
7. Image questions are often ignored.

While there are sometimes valid reasons for this (discussing colored output, or other issues where **the core of the question is visual in nature**), in most cases it is not useful and causes the problems listed above.

For help on formatting your posts, please see [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).